# Gradle shadow plugin failure: Error resolving plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I'm migrating the JAVA maven project to gradle. I've added a Shade plugin in maven but when i tried to replicate that in gradle its failing currently. Its failing at the time of clean, i.e., when I issue a below command,

```
gradle clean
```

Kindly find the pom.xml file and the corresponding build.gradle file below.

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myproj.integration</groupId>
<artifactId>Generic-Integration</artifactId>
<name>Generic-Integration</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>myproj-integration-${project.version}</finalName>

                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>

                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>jersey.repackaged</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>javassist</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.javassist</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>

                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.aopalliance</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.org.aopalliance</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.apache.logging</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.org.apache.logging</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.codehaus.jackson</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.glassfish.hk2</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.org.glassfish.hk2</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.glassfish.jersey</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.org.glassfish.jersey</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.json</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.org.json</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.jvnet</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.org.jvnet</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>

                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>javax.annotation</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.javax.annotation</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>javax.inject</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.javax.inject</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>javax.ws</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>myproj.repackaged.javax.ws</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.myproj.integration.ServiceExecuter</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>

                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.myproj:Util</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged</include>
                        <include>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl</include>
                        <include>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl</include>
                        <include>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs</include>
                        <include>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc</include>
                        <include>org.javassist:javassist</include>
                        <include>javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject</include>
                        <include>javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava</include>
                        <include>org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson</include>
                        <include>org.json:json</include>
                        <include>com.myproj:JAXRS</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproj</groupId>
        <artifactId>JAXRS</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproj</groupId>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

***build.gradle***

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.3'
    }

    shadowJar {
        artifactSet {
            include 'com.myproj:Util'
            include 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api'
            include 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils'
            include 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator'
            include 'org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator'
            include 'org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged'
            include 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl'
            include 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl'
            include 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs'
            include 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc'
            include 'org.javassist:javassist'
            include 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api'
            include 'org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject'
            include 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api'
            include 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client'
            include 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common'
            include 'org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava'
            include 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson'
            include 'org.json:json'
            include 'com.myproj:JAXRS'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'jersey.repackaged'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'javassist'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.javassist'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'org.aopalliance'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.org.aopalliance'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'org.apache.logging'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.org.apache.logging'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'org.codehaus.jackson'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'org.glassfish.hk2'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.org.glassfish.hk2'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'org.glassfish.jersey'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.org.glassfish.jersey'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'org.json'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.org.json'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'org.jvnet'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.org.jvnet'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'javax.annotation'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.javax.annotation'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'javax.inject'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.javax.inject'
        }
        relocation {
            pattern = 'javax.ws'
            shadedPattern = 'myproj.repackaged.javax.ws'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
      compile project(':JAXRS')
      compile project(':Server')
      testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.8.8'
      compile(group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-servlet', version:'8.1.16.v20140903') {
           /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
           This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
           Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */
      }
    }

    task genericIntegrationJar(type: Jar) {
        baseName = 'myproj-integration-1.2'
        from { configurations.external.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        with jar
    }

    test.useTestNG()
```

I'm getting the below exception, when i do a clean,

```
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Build file '/Users/mac8/POS/MobilePosSolution/Generic-Integration/build.gradle' line: 2

        * What went wrong:
        Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow', version: '1.2.3']
        > The response from https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.14.1/plugin/use/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow/1.2.3 was not a valid response from a Gradle Plugin Resolution Service: content type is 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1', expected 'application/json' (status code: 404)

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 4.903 secs
```

Kindly let me know if there is something that I need to change in my ***build.gradle*** file for replicating shade plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to hit it and looks like it's working fine:

```
curl -v https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.14.1/plugin/use/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow/1.2.3
*   Trying 104.25.173.23...
* Connected to plugins.gradle.org (104.25.173.23) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 704 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: ssl277771.cloudflaressl.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: EC
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain,CN=ssl277771.cloudflaressl.com
*    start date: Sat, 06 Aug 2016 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Sun, 05 Feb 2017 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=COMODO CA Limited,CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET /api/gradle/2.14.1/plugin/use/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow/1.2.3 HTTP/1.1
> Host: plugins.gradle.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 09:24:42 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d0c64c916428b3abd24c29d0578251d2d1472030681; expires=Thu, 24-Aug-17 09:24:41 GMT; path=/; domain=.gradle.org; HttpOnly
< Via: 1.1 vegur
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: 2d75c0b211512378-FRA
< 
{
  "id" : "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow",
  "version" : "1.2.3",
  "implementation" : {
    "gav" : "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3",
    "repo" : "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2"
  },
  "implementationType" : "M2_JAR",
  "legacy" : true
* Connection #0 to host plugins.gradle.org left intact
```

Try that and see what happens.

**--- edit**

Just added it to a sample project and the file gets downloaded fine. I also used `jcenter()` repository for dependencies.

```
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/1.2.3/shadow-1.2.3.jar
```

Add that to your **build.gradle** file and try

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing a curl is working fine. But when I do a **gradle clean** its failing and throwing that exception. Could you please let me know are there any alternatives for maven's shade plugin for gradle.

Comment: Just edited the response, please see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Still the same issue. 

`Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow', version: '1.2.3']
> The response from https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.14.1/plugin/use/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow/1.2.3 was not a valid response from a Gradle Plugin Resolution Service: content type is 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1', expected 'application/json' (status code: 404)`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :-

```
jar {
    baseName = 'Project name'
    // adds runtime dependencies to jar package
    from({configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}) {
        // remove all signature files
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE"
        exclude "META-INF/license"
        exclude "license/*"
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main class'
    } }
```